# Popup layer upon textarea

Tags: mobile, mobile-website

my project is a mobile web. in the home page there is a textarea in the middle, when user click a button, a pop-up layer jump out.

However, the layer is covered up the textarea, if user click a element on the pop-up layer,the textarea under the layer get focused.

How to prevent this textarea to get focused?

Answer (score 0):

Could you post a code snippet that illustrates the problem? Also, which mobile device and browser are you using?

One possible solution is to set the CSS `z-index` property of your popup and your textarea. Set the `z-index` of the popup to a higher value than the textarea so that it appears on top.

Comment: 【this is textarea div:  】  
<div class="kuangDiv">
      <textarea id="txtDiyContent" cols="" rows="" class="navInput" onpaste="Validator.LimitTextArea.HandleTextChange()" onchange="Validator.LimitTextArea.HandleTextChange()" onpropertychange="Validator.LimitTextArea.HandleTextChange()" onkeydown="Validator.LimitTextArea.HandleTextChange()">今天是2012年3月14日</textarea>
    </div>

【and this is the pop-up layer:    】
<div id="ckBlockUILayer" class="blockUI blockMsg blockPage" style="z-index: 1001;">

Comment: and we use webkit-core browser,we surpport android and ios devices

Comment: set the z-index is a good method on pc platform,but on mobile it seemed does not work~